# integral domains and field of fractions

Tags: abstract-algebra, category-theory

I've read about integral domains and their induced fields of fractions. For an integral domain $R$ its field of fractions $K$ is the "smallest" field that includes $R$, i.e. there is an injective map $L: R\to K$ and all injective maps $R \to K'$ for some field $K'$ factor through $L$.

When reading this I thought that this somehow reads like a universal property but I don't know what that should be.

Comment: It's not clear to me what you're confused about: what you just wrote down is a universal property.

Comment: You could also [take a look at Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Field_of_fractions#Construction), where it explicitly says *The field of fractions of $R$ is characterised by the following universal property: if $h:R\rightarrow F$ is an injective ring homomorphism from $R$ into a field $F$, then there exists a unique ring homomorphism $g:\mathrm{Quot}(R)\rightarrow F$ which extends $h$.*

Comment: I read the universal property on the "integral domain" article (where it was not called a universal property) and wasn't that far on the fraction field article (and I wouldn't expect universal property discussions in the construction section either...). Does it have a name and is applicable in other categories?

Answer (score 2):

It is a universal property, and is equivalent to the following adjointness: Let $\mathcal F : IntDom \to Fields$ be the functor from the category of integral domains and injective morphisms to the subcategory of fields, sending an integral domain $D$ to its fraction field, $F = \mathcal{F}(D)$.

Then, if $\mathcal{G} : Fields \to IntDom$ is the forgetful functor. For any field $I$,

$Hom_{IntDom}(D,\mathcal{G}(I))\cong Hom_{Fields}(\mathcal{F}(D),I)$.

This isn't saying much, but if you wanted to view it more categorically, you can. It just says the property you mentioned.

Comment: Maybe it's worth mentioning, that one must define the sets of morphisms in $IntDom$ to be the injective ring homomorphisms and not all of them to get the adjunction to work.

Comment: good point... my reason for this was just to show that it could be done. I will edit

Comment: Yes, this adjunction is a reflection and $\mathcal F$ is the reflector